# Running selenium test against multiple websites with a different sub-domain

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ruby

I have a test working when I hard code a URL in the ruby file for Selenium to execute however I need to run the same test against multiple URLS with just a different sub-domain

When I run the following I get an error that split is an unknown method

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome

pageLoad = sleep 1
subD = ARGV.split(",")
instances = []
subD.each do |test|
  instances << test
end
instances.each do |cub|
url = 'http://' + sub + '.test.com'
driver.get url
puts "#{url}"

begin
  driver.find_element(:id, 'user_login').send_keys 'user 1'
  driver.find_element(:id, 'user_password').send_keys 'password1'
  driver.find_element(:id, 'login_button').click
  puts 'Logging In'
rescue StandardError
  puts 'Unable to login'
end
pageLoad
puts 'Test Complete'
sleep 5
end
driver.quit
```

This is the error

```
test.rb:8:in `<main>': undefined method `split' for ["test1,test2,test3"]:Array (NoMethodError)
```

Inputting

```
ruby test.rb test1,test2,test3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARGV is an array not a string, you either need to pass each subdomain separately and then iterate through ARGV, or access the first member of ARGV with `ARGV[0]`